radix-ui/react-slider restricting on max range
I'm using @radix-ui/react-slider in a NextJS app, the data is coming from a Directus CMS. I am displaying a list of plans, each plan contains a price, and the price could be of any range from 0 to no limit on the maximum range
Radix Slider contains a max option which is a number value, I'm looking for something like 100,000+. Plus could be any range above 100,000. Is that something possible? Or any workaround to this problem?
